# Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, sass

I faced the below issue when I started to change CSS files extension to scss and also installing the node-sass module:

```
Error: Missing binding /home/shayan/workspace/react-ts-seed/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-72/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 12.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Unknown environment (.DS_Store)
  - OS X 64-bit with Node.js 17.x
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 14.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass` to download the binding for your current environment.
```

after removing node_module and installing the whole modules again as well as executing `npm rebuild node-sass` nothing happened.

**my node-sass version is node-sass@7.0.1**